# Implicit intent call scan

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new to Android development. And  I am trying build an app which scans all installed Apps for implicit intend calls. So if an application has implicit call then this app shows the name of the apps.  Can someone provide me some concept on how to do it? If this not possible, then is it possible to notify when application gets called implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all installed apps by querying the `PackageManager` and also get the Launch Intent for each package. (That is the packages with category `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get the list of all installed packages.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launcher Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

Comment: I still could not figure out how to determine whether intent is implicit or not. I tried to use resolveActivity (See above code snippet)

Comment: this is the only way to find the installedApps and its `Launch Intent`.